# How to connect with mqtt using websocket without using js libraries?

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt

I have a business requirement where I want to connect mqtt server(in my case using mosquito) without using available libraries like paho js or others. Instead of using libraries I want to use simply

```
var ws = new Websocket(maqtt_url);
```

After creating websocket connection I want to subscribe on a single topic and receive messages. Subscription to topic can be hard coded.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you use the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible, but your just going to end up re-writing all of the paho library yourself and including it in your application.

If you really want to go down this path then the MQTT spec can be found [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) which will tell you the  format of the

- Connection Packet
- Subscription Packet
- Message Packet
- Keep Alive Packet

all of which you will need to implement in order to maintain a connection to the broker.

Comment: Is not there an easy way to just connect and subscribe

Comment: MQTT is a full network protocol, you will need to implement pretty much all of it to do what you want. It will be significantly easier just to include the library in your project. The license should allow reuse under nearly any circumstances

Answer (score 1):

An mqtt over websockets example with encoding of the mqtt protocol data without using a library is available [here](https://github.com/urutech/simple-mqtt-ws). It maybe a good starting point for developing applications.

Comment: You should post the code in the answer instead of providing a link to the unofficial, moreover your own, github repo. The code in the gihub can disappear anytime making the answer lose all of its value